# What are differences between index and item method of QStandardItemModel?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

My friends, Could you please explain the concept of these methods to me? Normally, when I get a data I would use 'index' to refer to items in a model and specify roles via data attribute. I came across 'item' method today and the explanation of this method is "Returns the item for the given row and column if one has been set; otherwise returns 0." What are differences from 'index'+'data' method? Is it just a shortcut?

This is the documentation of 'item' method. 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#item

Alternatively, this is the documentation of 'index' method.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#index

Comment: Qt treats models as though they are hierarchical one or two dimensional arrays, hierarchical because each 'array' containing items can have a parent item. QModelIndex objects just encapsulate the parent, row and column information into a single object you can reference and pass around, but those 'co-ordinates' are still in there and QModelIndex object still have a parent, row and column. Really it's the QModelIndex objects that are the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try my best to explain it.

The item is like the actual widget you see in the view (it's not actually a widget, but I think it's a good way to think about it). It's what the user is actually seeing.

The index is more "behind the scenes." It's like a pointer to a position in the model.

An item can exist without an index. But a valid index cannot exist without an item. The item only associates with an index when it is put into a model. Otherwise, it's just an item that no one can look at.

Take an array as an example... It contains multiple "items". You specify which item from the array you want by providing a number, aka the index. Simply put, the index only exists when it is associated with an item in the array. But the item can exist outside of the array and be it's own thing without an index.

The QModelIndex was created to be a lightweight way to reference items in a model. Similar to the way you can use a number to represent an object stored in an array.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion regarding choose one rather than the other? As per my understanding from your answers, 'item' method can get a job done if I want to get only a value of items, but not to edit them because they don't provide an index. I'm not sure whether I understand this correctly.

Comment: @PaKaNoSuKiKeNuiChaZaP You can edit the items. `QStandardItem` can also [provide you an index](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#index). See the [docs for `QStandardItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html).

Comment: No you really can't choose one or the other. They work hand in hand. And no, you can ONLY edit the data through the "item." since that is where the data is held. You can store data in an item and it doesnt need to have an index. It only gets an index when it is put into a model. Index can only read the data. Honestly, just start using them. It will make sense as you continue. Long story short, you dont "pick" one to work with. You use both all the time.

Comment: @mrg95 Technically you can also edit the data using the index with [`QStandardItemModel::setData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setData). Internally this uses [`QStandardItemModel::itemFromIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemFromIndex) though.

Comment: But you see, the index just returns the item. It's just like a pointer to the item. You cannot set data using index alone. That will just confuse him

Comment: To summarize @PaKaNoSuKiKeNuiChaZaP, the item has ALL the data. Put that item in a model and it now has an index. If you want to set the data of the item when it's in a model, you first need to have access to the item. Either you store all the items yourself with a neat way to remember which one is which (don't do that), OR you use the handy-dandy `QModelIndex` which does that for you. For example, `QTreeView::currentIndex()` gives the index you are currently focused on. But you can't set it's data, so you need to use `QStandardItemModel::itemFromIndex()` to get the item, THEN set the data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will try it soon.

Comment: No problem! Any questions just let me know.